# Extract prefix from multiple files and rename by adding as suffix

Tags: bash, shell

Currently multiple files are in a folder with name as :

`yyyymmdd_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab`

Example:

```
20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab
```

I want to rename all files with naming convention as :

```
XPL_PNL_Attribution_2016-03-01
```

The file(s) have to be renamed to meet the general naming convention (`XPL_PNL_Attribution_yyyy-mm-dd`) :

1) The first particle should be the "class" which means the filename prefix, up to the first underscore, need to add a prefix (`XPL_PNL Attribution_`) to the filename

2) the date part of the filename should be `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `yyyymmdd` like it is here, need to add the dashes

Comment: I don't see where the "PNL" comes from in your "want to rename" sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by splitting the filename into fields, separated by underscores.

```
$ f=20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab
$ IFS=_
$ a=( ${f%.*} )
$ declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="20160301" [1]="TCT" [2]="XPL" [3]="PLA" [4]="Attribution")'
$ new="$(printf '%s_%s_%s_%s' "${a[2]}" "${a[3]}" "${a[4]}" "${a[0]:0:4}-${a[0]:4:2}-${a[0]:6:2}")"
```

Scripting this to handle a directory of files requires a for loop:

```
IFS=_
for f in *.tab; do
  a=( ${f%.*} )
  new="$(printf '%s_%s_%s_%s' "${a[2]}" "${a[3]}" "${a[4]}" "${a[0]:0:4}-${a[0]:4:2}-${a[0]:6:2}")"
  mv -v "$f" "$new"
done
```

Alternately, you could gather the filename parts using a regex:

```
$ [[ $f =~ ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^.]+) ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution" [1]="20160301" [2]="TCT" [3]="XPL" [4]="PLA" [5]="Attribution")'
```

Scripting this would work the same way, only you'd refer to the `$BASH_REMATCH[]` array instead of `$a[]`, and you wouldn't need to mess with `$IFS`.

```
for f in *.tab; do
  [[ $f =~ ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^.]+) ]]
  new="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}_${BASH_REMATCH[4]}_${BASH_REMATCH[5]}_${BASH_REMATCH[0]:0:4}-${BASH_REMATCH[0]:4:2}-${BASH_REMATCH[0]:6:2}"
  mv -v "$f" "$new"
done
```

Comment: Was there a reason to use setting `IFS` globally instead of `IFS=_ read ymd _ rest`? Which also limits the splitting to the fields desired?

Comment: @EtanReisner - .. only my laziness. Yes, `read` is an excellent suggestion. As always, tmtowtdi.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using Bash parameter substitution :

```
for f in *.tab; do
    mv "${f}" XPL_PNL_Attribution_"${f:0:4}"-"${f:4:2}"-"${f:6:2}";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab" | sed -e "s/^\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)_....\([^.]*\).\(.*\)$/\4_\1-\2-\3.\5/g" | sed -e "s/_PLA_/_PNL_/g"
```

or

```
echo "20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab" | sed -e "s/^\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\).*_\([^.]*\).\(.*\)$/XPL_PNL_\4_\1-\2-\3.\5/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, undebugged, untested, but flexible on incoming file names, assuming the TCT field is always to be discarded.

```
# 20160301_TCT_XPL_PLA_Attribution.tab
# XPL_PNL_Attribution_2016-03-01
#                  1                 2            3                        4
file_out="$( echo "$file_in" | 
    sed -r -e 's/^\([12][0-9]{3}\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)_[A-Za-z]+_\(.*\)\.tab/($4)_$1-$2-$3/'
   )";
   mv "$file_in" "$file_out"
```